# How to get x and y in same size from .CSV file to plot scatterplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to reshape the array with some .csv value and it' giving me an error for multiple lines and I have tried to find some examples over a StackOverflow but I wasn't able to figure it out what's the actual problem here !! and I'm getting this error every time - whenever I'm trying to use np.zeros(), np.ones(), and np.array()

I have exam data that consist EXAM-1, EXAM-2 and Admission decision. My x, y, and theta are not in the same size?

```
def sigmoid(z):
    new_val = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))
    return new_val  

def h(theta,X):
    return sigmoid(np.dot(X,theta))#------Value Error    


def compute_logistic_cost(theta, X, y):
    m= len(y)
    J = (1/m) * np.sum((-y * np.log(h(theta,X))) - ((1 - y)*np.log(1 - h(theta,X))))#-----Value Error

    eps = 1e-12
    hypothesis[hypothesis < eps] = eps
    eps = 1.0 - 1e-12
    hypothesis[hypothesis > eps] = eps

    return J

X = np.ones( (3, 1) )#------Value Error and If I put 100 instead of 1 it is working
X[1:,:] = X.T

theta = np.zeros( (3, 1) )
print(compute_logistic_cost(theta, X, y))#------Value Error

theta = np.array([[1.0],
              [1.0],
              [1.0]])
print(compute_logistic_cost(theta, X, y))

theta = np.array([[0.1],
              [0.1],
              [0.1]])
print(compute_logistic_cost(theta, X, y))
```

Following is the error message please help me to understand. *ValueError: shapes (3,100) and (3,1) not aligned: 100 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)*

Comment: Your code raises `NameError: name 'x' is not defined` here (after fixing the indentation errors).

Comment: Thank you for catching the error!!! Can you please help me to understand the glitch in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a mathematical failure - taking the dot product of the two matrices will fail due to matrix incompatibility. See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) for the doc showing this value error. Specifically:

```
Raises: 

ValueError

    If the last dimension of a is not the same size as the second-to-last dimension of b.
```

Matrix math is hard. It looks like you just need the tranpose of the smaller matrix for the dot product to successfully execute. I do not know enough to tell you whether the rest of the script is correct, but this will at least clear the error for you to continue.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have tried to reshape the matrics for transpose but was not able to do it. Do you have any suggestions in code ?

Comment: It looks like you're attempting to transpose lowercase x, while the array is held in uppercase X. Python variables are case-sensitive. Try ```X.T``` instead of ```x.T```.

Comment: I had the wrong indentation in the question and I have fixed it, and I have tried X.T but it's still showing me an error.